How to Publish Custom Teams App to Azure from Visual Studio 2022
I need your help I'm not expert creating Custom Teams App, this is my first App and I'm creating a Custom Teams App in Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 (Blazor), the App is ready I Already finished and every time I executed Locally the APP works fine if I execute it directly from Visual Studio 2022. I already upload the manifest.json to Teams App and the Teams Administrator already approved and now I can see the Icon in the lists of applications inside Teams but when I press to the App the first Page is empty(I suppose should be first publish the Custom Teams App to Azure according waht I read).
I'm waiting the administrators assign me the missing privileges to publish to Azure directly from Visual Studio 2022 (I received an error that I don't have privileges).
My question is... after the App is published to Azure what should I modify in the Package to make the Custom Teams App works in Teams? There are some files that I was reading that should be modified but those files have some variables that I don't understand what it means and where I can get the values.
For example the files manifest.json, .env.local, .env.local, launchSettings.json, etc. by default those files have some values but I don't know what I should modify in these files to change it from Development to Production environment.
I'm attaching the images of those files and there are variables like TEAMS_APP_ID, TAB_ENDPOINT, TEAMSFX_ENV, APP_NAME_SUFFIX, TAB_DOMAIN, TEAMS_APP_TENANT_ID once the App is published to Azure what value should I change and if can I get those values from Azure?
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
How to Publish Custom Teams App to Azure from Visual Studio 2022

Check if the below solution helps to fix the issue.

Before deploying the Microsoft Teams app to Azure, provision the resources in Visual studio.

Navigate to Project=>Teams Toolkit=>Provision in the cloud:



Select the Subscription, Resource group and click on Provision:



This way you can provision the resources required for the deployment:
Summary:
(√) Done: Lifecycle stage provision was executed successfully.
  (√) Done: aadApp/create was executed successfully.
    (√) Done: Created Microsoft Entra application with object id edffa21d-d79e-427d-bbee-67498a7b61c6
    (√) Done: Generated client secret for Microsoft Entra application with object id edffa21d-d79e-427d-bbee-67498a7b61c6
  (√) Done: teamsApp/create was executed successfully.
    (√) Done: Teams app 90d9ce64-f33e-4291-937f-0ee1da3a572f created successfully
  (√) Done: arm/deploy was executed successfully.
    (√) Done: ARM templates are deployed successfully. Resource group name: pravrg. Deployment name: Create-resources-for-tab
  (√) Done: aadApp/update was executed successfully.
    (√) Done: Applied manifest ./aad.manifest.json to Microsoft Entra application with object id edffa21d-d79e-427d-bbee-67498a7b61c6
  (√) Done: teamsApp/validateManifest was executed successfully.
  (√) Done: teamsApp/zipAppPackage was executed successfully.
  (√) Done: teamsApp/validateAppPackage was executed successfully.
  (√) Done: teamsApp/update was executed successfully.
    (√) Done: Teams app 90d9ce64-f33e-4291-937f-0ee1da3a572f updated successfully
  (√) Done: teamsApp/extendToM365 was executed successfully.
    (√) Done: The Microsoft 365 title has been acquired successfully (U_565d847b-cdb1-f0ac-57e0-560882d1db04).

9/9 actions in provision stage executed successfully.

The values for the settings you mentioned will be added automatically in .env.dev:
My .env.dev:
# Generated values during provision, you can define your own variables.

TEAMS_APP_ID=90d9ce64-fXXXX572f
AAD_APP_CLIENT_ID=9ac29557-c4XXXXX80a43
AAD_APP_OBJECT_ID=edffa21XXXXXa7b61c6
AAD_APP_ACCESS_AS_USER_PERMISSION_ID=bb5e02bXXXXXca4359a
AAD_APP_TENANT_ID=72f98XXXXXX011db47
AAD_APP_OAUTH_AUTHORITY_HOST=https://login.microsoftonline.com
AAD_APP_OAUTH_AUTHORITY=https://login.microsoftonline.com/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47
TAB_AZURE_APP_SERVICE_RESOURCE_ID=/subscriptions/d9XXXXX-4732-XX589e52bc/resourceGroups/pravrg/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/ssotabea8c47
TAB_ENDPOINT=https://ssoXXXXea8c47.azurewebsites.net

TEAMS_APP_TENANT_ID=72f98XXXXXX-2d7cd011db47
TAB_DOMAIN=ssotXXXXXXa8c47.azurewebsites.net
TAB_HOSTNAME=ssoXXXXXX8c47.azurewebsites.net
M365_TITLE_ID=U_565d847XXXXXX60882d1db04
M365_APP_ID=d55c7c98-d88XXXXXXa874ea8a

Deploy the app using Visual studio:

Navigate to Project=>Teams Toolkit=>Deploy to the cloud:

Executing deploy
    // Removed few logs
Executing lifecycle deploy
Executing action cli/runDotnetCommand in lifecycle deploy
Start to run command: "%ComSpec% /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL dotnet publish --configuration Release MyTeamsApp6.csproj"" with args: 
    // Removed few logs
Action cli/runDotnetCommand in lifecycle deploy succeeded with output {}
Executing action azureAppService/zipDeploy in lifecycle deploy
Get Microsoft Entra token successfully. Upload zip package through AAD Auth mode.
Start to upload zip file to https://ssotabea8c47.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy?isAsync=true
Upload zip file to https://ssotabea8c47.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy?isAsync=true complete, response: {"status":202,"statusText":"Accepted","headers":{},"config":{"headers":{},"data":{}},"request":{},"data":""}.
Check deploy status with location: https://ssotabea8c47.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest?deployer=ZipDeploy&time=2024-08-01_10-14-00Z
Check deploy status response: {"status":200,"statusText":"OK","headers":{},"config":{"headers":{}},"request":{},"data":{"status":4}}
Start send telemetry data {"time_cost":"18406","status":"4","message":"Created via a push deployment","received_time":"2024-08-01T10:14:00.5509503Z","started_time":"2024-08-01T10:14:00.6603294Z","end_time":"2024-08-01T10:14:00.8947021Z","last_success_end_time":"2024-08-01T10:14:00.8947021Z","complete":"true","active":"true","is_readonly":"true","site_name_hash":"660f089e06f8c633dedcb6c2014c8ad9f88a7dc5dd269affdc224bdce8534594"}
Action azureAppService/zipDeploy in lifecycle deploy succeeded with output {}
Finished Executing lifecycle deploy. Result: {}
Execution summary:

Summary:
(√) Done: Lifecycle stage deploy was executed successfully.
  (√) Done: cli/runDotnetCommand was executed successfully.
    (√) Done: Successful execution of the `dotnet publish --configuration Release MyTeamsApp6.csproj` command at `C:\Users\uname\Source\Repos\MyTeamsApp\MyTeamsApp`.
  (√) Done: azureAppService/zipDeploy was executed successfully.
    (√) Done: Successfully deployed `C:\Users\uname\Source\Repos\MyTeamsApp\MyTeamsApp\bin\Release\net8.0\publish` to Azure App Service.

Deployed the app to Azure:
Portal:

